# DCE (Dynamic Content Element) access tab for each field within a section

Tags: typo3, tx-dce

I'm seeking a method to incorporate both a publish date and an expiration date for every field within a section using the Dynamic Content Element (DCE).

I'm aware of how to implement this for the overall DCE element.

Could you please advise if there's a similar approach for individual fields?
[image]

Comment: TYPO3 handles the enableFields (eg starttime/stoptime) on a record basis when querying the database. Therefore, there is no out-of-the-box solution for individual fields.
But maybe you could describe your use case, because"for every field" sounds a bit strange as a requirement.

Comment: I have a Slider DCE.  Each field {field.slides.n} has a title {field.slides.n.title}, a link, ...

I would like to have the ability to individually enable/disable each slide.

Comment: Ah, "field" in the meaning of DCE... I'm currently not deep in DCE anymore, but maybe mapping your Slides to tt_content could solve it: https://docs.typo3.org/p/t3/dce/main/en-us/AdditionalInformations/TcaMapping.html